# How to dissolve hardened aluminum silicate beads back into solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

TLDR: We use the adsorber beads (which is essentially alumino-silicate beads) to adsorb some  stuff from our process stream. The spent beads are dissolved in NaOH and sent to our wastewater treatment facility for precipitation and separation through filter presses.
Anyway, due to unavoidable circumstances, the dissolved beads in caustic solution was held up overnight before it could be pumped to wastewater treatment. The dissolved beads solidified in the vat, and would not re-dissolve on adding excess caustic. To be clear, it does dissolve only at the top of the vat, but cannot penetrate the interiors.
Can someone explain the chemistry of what might have formed (polymerization, silica gel, etc?) and how do I go about dissolving it? Should I just blast some holes in the solid with pressurized water, and then put caustic into it for increased penetration?

Much appreciated.

Comment: The chemistry of alkaline silicate is not yet perfectly understood. In the industry, sodium silicate is produced by fusing silica and $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{Na2CO3}$. In both case the obtained sodium silicate is nearly insoluble in water. But it can be dissolved by using hot pressurized water. That is the way "liquid glass" is obtained. Why don't you try  using pressurized water ? Start with cold water, and try hot water in case of failure.